How properly use JupterLab with Nginx?
I've installed Jupter Lab on a VPS which running fine. Now I want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy. On the Internet I found the following working location configuration:
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}

Again this works when I got to https://example.org/. However I would like to use a different location, but when I change the location to, say:
location /jupyter/ {
    # no changes in here
}

Now, if I go to https://example.org/jupyter/ I get an "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error. I'm rather new to Nginx, so I'm not sure what I might be missing here?
EDIT 1: Chrome actually tells me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
